# Парсинг строки вида (1,"qqq","www")

Tags: python, строки, парсер

Читаю из файла последовательно строки вида:

```
1,"AAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBB"
2,"CCCCCCCCC","DDDDDDDDD"
3,"EEEEEEEEE","FFFFFFFFF"
...
1000,"GGGGGGGGG","HHHHHHHHHH"
```

Как их распарсить и получить отдельные строки:

```
# First String: 1
# Second String: AAAAAAAAA
# Third String: BBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что вы действительно "юзали поиск".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Питон, код по вашим уточняющим комментариям:

```
line = '1,"AAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBB"'
print(line.split(',')[1][1:-1])
```

Вывод:

```
AAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: str = `1,"AAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBB"`
result = str.split('\"')
print (f"Res1: {result[1]}") # получаем AAAAAAAAA

Ваш код эффективнее, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Укажите язык на котором пишите пожалуйста.
Приведу пример на JS:
Для каждой строки нужно применить метод split:

```
let str = `1,"AAAAAAAAA","BBBBBBBBB"`
let result = str.split(`,`)
// ["1", "\"AAAAAAAAA\"", "\"BBBBBBBBB\""] - результат
```

В `split` передается аргумент - строка/символ по которой будет разделена исходная строка. В `result` массив из трех элементов, каждый из которого вы можете получить обратившись с помощью индекса.

P.S. Так как Вы указали, что Вы не программист, задавайте свои вопросы в комментарии - постараюсь помочь

Comment: Пытаюсь писать на питоне. Значения нужны без кавычек. Значения в кавычках разной длины! В идеале нужен только второе значение: AAAAAA